# How to convert multiple columns to single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a onehot-encoded columns,df with zeros as "nan". I'm trying to convert onehot encoded columns to a single column.

Assume the below dataframe, df

```
    p1   |   p2  |   p3   |  p4   |  p5   |
---------------------------------------
0   cat     nan     nan     nan      nan
1   nan     dog     nan     nan      nan
2   nan     nan     horse   nan      nan
3   nan     nan     nan     donkey   nan
4   nan     nan     nan     nan      pig
```

**Required Output**

```
    animals
-----------------
0   cat
1   dog
2   horse
3   donkey
4   pig
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive with your question, it will help a lot with the other developers to read and share solutions to this problem. e.g. whether you are looking for a SQL query or code in some language to do this? and how currently you are doing? Will recommend following StackOverflow Q&A guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is always only one non missing value per rows use forward filling missing values (like [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`) and then select last column by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), also for one column `DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].to_frame('new')
print (df)
      new
0     cat
1     dog
2   horse
3  donkey
4     pig
```

If possible more non missing values per rows use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `join` per first level:

```
print (df)
    p1   p2     p3      p4    p5
0  cat  NaN    NaN     NaN  lion
1  NaN  dog    NaN     NaN   NaN
2  NaN  NaN  horse     NaN   NaN
3  NaN  NaN    NaN  donkey   NaN
4  NaN  NaN    NaN     NaN   pig

df2 = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join).to_frame('new')
print (df2)
         new
0  cat, lion
1        dog
2      horse
3     donkey
4        pig
```

Or lambda function:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep=', '), axis=1).to_frame('new')
print (df2)
         new
0  cat, lion
1        dog
2      horse
3     donkey
4        pig
```

Comment: Given the OP's example even `np.diag(df)` would work... but that's not likely not to be a practical solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you have one word per row you can fill `NaN` with empty strings and sum by row:

```
df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0       cat
1       dog
2     horse
3    donkey
4       pig
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly but working. Not sure what you expect if you have >1 not NA for the same index.

```
df['animals'] = df[df.columns[0]]
for c in df.columns[1:]:
   df['animals'].fillna(df[c], inplace=True)
```