# Convert single column to multiple, ensuring column count on last line

Tags: csv, awk

I would like to use AWK (Windows) to convert a text file with a single column to multiple columns - the count specified in the script or on the command line.

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085247/how-to-convert-multiple-columns-to-single-column) but my **final data file needs to have the same column count all the way.**

Example of input:

```
L1
L2
L3
L4
L5
L6
L7
```

split into 3 columns and ";" as a separator

```
L1;L2;L3
L4;L5;L6
L7;;        <<< here two empty fields are created after end of file, since I used just one on this line.
```

I tried to modify variants of the typical solution given: `NR%4 {printf $0",";next} 1;`  and a counter, but could not quite get it right.

I would prefer not to count lines before, thereby running over the file multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v n=3 '{
   sub(/\r$/, "")   # removes DOS line break, if present
   printf "%s", $0(NR%n ? ";" : ORS)
}
END {
   # now we need to add empty columns in last record
   if (NR % n) {
      for (i=1; i < (n - (NR % n)); ++i)
         printf ";"
      print ""
   }
}' file

L1;L2;L3
L4;L5;L6
L7;;
```

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I needed. I had to change linefeed to `\r\n`  (for Windows), but other than that, nice solution that is pure awk.

Comment: @MyICQ, Good that you have accepted this nice answer. Request you to please do check other answers also so that other answerers could be aware, cheers.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the very good point on using `RS/ORS` instead of hardcoded `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `xargs` + `awk` combination to achieve the outcome needed by OP.

```bash
xargs -n3 < Input_file | 
awk -v OFS=";" '{if(NF==1){$0=$0";;"};if(NF==2){$0=$0";"};$1=$1} 1'
```

Comment: This could work, and is shorter, but I do not have xargs. This is for a Windows machine, and although I could get GNU versions, I prefer to keep it single-exe.

Answer (score 1):

For an `awk` I would do:

```
awk -v n=3 '
{printf("%s%s", $0, (NR%n>0) ? ";" : ORS)}
END{
    for(i=NR%n; i<n-1; i++) printf(";")
    printf ORS
}' file
```

Or, an alternative `awk`:

```
awk -v n=3 -v OFS=";" '
{ row=row ? row FS $0 : $0 }           # build row of n fields
!(NR%n) {$0=row; NF=n; print; row="" } # split the fields sep by OFS
END { if (NR%n) { $0=row; NF=n; print } }  # same
' file
```

Or you can use `ruby` if you want more options:

```
ruby -le '
n=3
puts $<.read.
    split($/).
    each_slice(n).
    map{|sl| sl.fill(sl.size...n) { "" }; sl.join(";") }.
    join($\) # By using $\ and $/ with the -l the RS and ORS is set correctly for the platform
' file
```

Or, realize that `paste` is designed to do this:

```
paste -d';' - - - <file
```

(Use a `-` for each column desired)

Any of those prints (with `n=3`):

```
L1;L2;L3
L4;L5;L6
L7;;
```

(And work correctly for other values of `n`...)